# Create 2 vectors where 1 vector is associated with another, then converted into a list

Tags: r

I am new to R so please be nice to me. I have a vector called flood that is associated with flood_level. I have another vector called year that must be associated with flood_level, which is associated with flood. In the end, all of this must come together in list format, like so: 
[image]

I am having trouble getting to the result in the picture and I don't know what code to type to get there. Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
flood = c(1,2,3,3,2,1,2,2,3,1,1,1,1,3,2)
flood_level = factor(flood, labels = c("low", "medium", "high"))
year = c(2001:2015)
my_df = data.frame(year, flood_level)
my_df
flood_year = as.list(my_df)
```

Comment: `split(my_df$year, my_df$flood_level)` OR `split(year, flood_level)`

Comment: OMG, you're a lifesaver! Thank you so much. It worked!